# Extracting minimum pixel value from multiple rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, values

[image][image]

I am trying to extract minimum values from about 300 raster files (GeoTIFF) - for example an output table containing raster names against their minimum values. I would like to automate the process. I have searched this and found most results use ArcGIS Pro. Is it is possible to replicate the processes in ArcGIS Desktop (and Model Builder)?

I have tried following python code but got error message.

```
import arcpy

#Get the geoprocessing result object

Result = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("D:\New folder\LOSasc.tif", "MINIMUM")

minresult= Result.getOutput(0)`
```

error message:

`Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 3, in File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 14996, in GetRasterProperties raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 001100: Failed because no statistics are available. Failed to execute (GetRasterProperties)`

Is this command correct for what I want?
Can it be used for extracting min values from all 300 Geotif?
Why am I getting such error?

Comment: Questions need to be able to answer the questions "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" Right now you only have the task, not a problem. Please [Edit] the Question to report the software you have chosen, what you tried, and the error or other problem encountered.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: `gdalinfo` gives you this information by default, but there's probably a cleaner way

Comment: The error message you posted in the duplicate is needed to reopen this. 99% of the time, Pro documentation will be the same as ArcMap, and it certainly is in this case, so dismissing the search results because it's linked to Pro is unwise.

Comment: @coral I have recently done similar process, calculated mean, using modelbuilder. I am not sure, if I can write answer as comment or not, so, it would be better to edit your question and reopen it. Then, I could share the steps needed.

Comment: could you please write me here  because i am confused that what should i do... edit  this post again and delete new question  or vice versa.  Getting low pixel value for each raster using ArcMap [duplicate] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440184/getting-low-pixel-value-for-each-raster-using-arcmap

Comment: It can be seem confusing at first. I suggest to go through [help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help) section quickly to get some ideas. Meanwhile, you should edit this post with more details - what are you trying to achieve, what have you done so far, and where have you got stuck; that's what Vince mentioned earlier. I reckon doing these would help to reopen this question.

Comment: Add the new information from the repost, and this can be reopened..You should also add a single line to your script to calculate statistics, to see if that addresses your issue.

Comment: Thank you  now I am searching about calculate statistic as what you said but Could you please help me more to do it because I need this table as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the process in ModelBuilder using raster iterator. You may need two models: one for iteration and another for final output.

First, using raster iterator you can access all rasters stored in a GDB/folder one by one. Run zonal statistics to calculate min value for each iteration and save it to a table by joining. This is a sub-model. You model would look something similar.

[image]

In step-2, you call the created sub-model. Direct this main-model to raster data source(GDB/folder), vector file containing boundary, and the field based on the joining would take place. Finally, you can export the result as table or excel file. As you can see, I called sub-model "loop" to iterate all raster images.

[image]

A model can be added, as sub-model, to another model by simply clicking on "Add data or tool" button and direct it insite toolbox where the model is saved (or created). I mention this, as I had to spent few good minutes to figure it out when I started using modelBuilder - not many resources dictating step-by-step process to add sub-model.

Comment: thank you so much.I appreciate your help. now I am starting to do as you planed and i will ask you if i face problem .

Comment: Hi is this solution for a specific location  because my GEOTIFS are distributed and  not just for one place  , they are not in the same size as well .

Comment: Hi Mr Salit as you said the first step is like this. I do not know how to solve this error. I choose zone and raster the same ,for example :(aizad.tiff ) is the error about it? I attached  image of steps and error  above

Comment: Hi Mr Salit as you said the first step is like this. I do not know how to solve this error. I choose zone and raster the same ,for example :(aizad.tiff ) is the error about it? I attached image above

Comment: I do not see the image you've shared. But, have a look at official documentation of zonal statistics if you are stuck at it. [zonalStatistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics.htm)

Comment: Ok, I see, you've added image to the original question. It could add confusion for future users - I'd refrain doing it hence. I suppose, you are getting such error because your value raster and zone raster are identical. Read the documentation I shared in previous comment - it would help to understand the tool better.

Comment: hi again I understood that I need limitation as shape (vector) and raster file for one region .I did it for one raster completely and I gained table of  minimum value  with 2 inputs Aizad,tif and Aizad.shp  so for using loop we have iterator raster is there any way to have iterator shp with same name of  tif to relate them .I attached picture

Comment: Why do you need iterator shp for? The raster iterator should do the trick. Also, please read the answer I posted - you'd need two models, one for iterating through all raster inputs and one main model to save the outputs (this does not iterate). 
If you use just the iterator, it would replace the old values in each iteration and only the final iteration's result will be saved.

Comment: Hi I need iterator  for shp : because of different tif limitation for example  aizad.tif  has aizad.shp then   farton.tif  has farton.shp and so on I am sure I will solve this problem with your guidance .  I clarify the inputs of zonal statistics table in image( I attached ) and as you said I am reading and thinking about your answer .thank you so much

Comment: hi finally I solved it .thank you so much  can I answer my question ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
hi finally I solved it .thank you so much can I answer my question ?

Comment: Can you put more explanation in your answer? If the other person helped you with this be sure to upvote it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi of course I will try to explain more  you know for using zonal statistic as table (that is mentioned by Mr Salit)  I have to provide two items ,as you can see in image above one of them is " input raster or feature zone data "and the other one is " input value raster " .so  I have to have Boundary  or vector file of my Geo tiffs (as shape file format=input raster or feature zone data) for each of them and relate one by one to each other in zonal statistics so  I used parse path to get name of tiffs in this procedure and it worked then using raster domain.

Comment: at the end I used append item to add or append one by one of minimum value extraction for each GEO TIFF in " output table "of zonal statistic table.  model builder diagram shows these steps. please feedback me if is it sufficient or help full or not ?